# Query - Pivoting 2 columns into 2 rows

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am familiar with PIVOTS but have done only simple ones of one column into a row.

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATE
SET @EndDate ='20160728' --{?EndDate}

SELECT T1.ItemCode,SUM(T0.IssuedQty) [Litres],SUM(T1.CmpltQty) [Tons]
FROM    WOR1 T0 INNER JOIN
        OWOR T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry INNER JOIN
        OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
WHERE   T0.ItemCode ='FURNACE OIL/0001' AND T1.Type ='S' AND 
        (T1.PostDate BETWEEN (SELECT Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, @EndDate), 0)) AND @EndDate)
GROUP BY T1.ItemCode
```

This returns the results:

[image]

What do I need to do is to get the following results but I'm unsure how.

[image]

How do I achieve this?

EDIT: The one highlighted as duplicate is different. It is joining 2 queries for additional columns. I just need 1 query transposed to take 2 columns into rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134378/joining-2-queries-to-match-months-side-by-side

Comment: The onle highlighted is joining 2 queries for additional columns. I just need 1 query transposed to take 2 columns into rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpivot with rows converted to columns as well as columns converted to rows](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122665/unpivot-with-rows-converted-to-columns-as-well-as-columns-converted-to-rows)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this I suppose:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATE
SET @EndDate ='20160728' --{?EndDate}

SELECT 
    A.LineType,
    CASE B.ItemCode WHEN 'FG/RM/001' THEN CASE A.LineType WHEN 'Litres' THEN SUM(B.IssuedQty) WHEN 'Tons' THEN SUM(B.CmpltQty) ELSE Null END END AS [FG/RM/001],
    CASE B.ItemCode WHEN 'FG/RM/002' THEN CASE A.LineType WHEN 'Litres' THEN SUM(B.IssuedQty) WHEN 'Tons' THEN SUM(B.CmpltQty) ELSE Null END END AS [FG/RM/002],
    CASE B.ItemCode WHEN 'FG/RM/003' THEN CASE A.LineType WHEN 'Litres' THEN SUM(B.IssuedQty) WHEN 'Tons' THEN SUM(B.CmpltQty) ELSE Null END END AS [FG/RM/003],
    CASE B.ItemCode WHEN 'FG/RM/004' THEN CASE A.LineType WHEN 'Litres' THEN SUM(B.IssuedQty) WHEN 'Tons' THEN SUM(B.CmpltQty) ELSE Null END END AS [FG/RM/004],
    CASE B.ItemCode WHEN 'FG/RM/005' THEN CASE A.LineType WHEN 'Litres' THEN SUM(B.IssuedQty) WHEN 'Tons' THEN SUM(B.CmpltQty) ELSE Null END END AS [FG/RM/005],
    CASE B.ItemCode WHEN 'FG/RM/006' THEN CASE A.LineType WHEN 'Litres' THEN SUM(B.IssuedQty) WHEN 'Tons' THEN SUM(B.CmpltQty) ELSE Null END END AS [FG/RM/006],
    CASE B.ItemCode WHEN 'FG/RM/007' THEN CASE A.LineType WHEN 'Litres' THEN SUM(B.IssuedQty) WHEN 'Tons' THEN SUM(B.CmpltQty) ELSE Null END END AS [FG/RM/007]
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'Litres' AS LineType
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Tons' AS LineType
    ) A
CROSS JOIN 
    (
        SELECT T1.ItemCode,SUM(T0.IssuedQty) [Litres],SUM(T1.CmpltQty) [Tons]
        FROM    WOR1 T0 INNER JOIN
                OWOR T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry INNER JOIN
                OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode
        WHERE   T0.ItemCode ='FURNACE OIL/0001' AND T1.Type ='S' AND 
                (T1.PostDate BETWEEN (SELECT Dateadd(month, Datediff(month, 0, @EndDate), 0)) AND @EndDate)
        GROUP BY T1.ItemCode
    ) B
GROUP BY 
    A.LineType
```